# Detect image input loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, onload

I was using this code:

```
<input type="image" ... onLoad="this.style.opacity = 1" />
```

It works fine in IE (at least, the versions that support `opacity` :p) but in Chrome the `onLoad` event did not fire when the image loaded.

Note that the `src` attribute of the input can change, and when it does some JavaScript sets the `opacity` to 0 first, and suitable `transition` properties make it look like the image fades out and the new one fades in. Also, use of `<input type="image">` is required because the server needs the coordinates.

I have jerry-rigged it using an absolutely-positioned `<img>` taking the `onLoad` and `opacity`, placed behind the `<input>` that now uses a transparent GIF pixel. While it works, it's ugly.

Is there any way to detect the successful loading of an image used in an `<input>` in Chrome, or is this like `background-image`, undetectable?

EDIT: In case it helps, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKpYW/1/)

Comment: Instead of using an `img` behind the input, you could use a detached `img` and use its load handler to do what you want, as often used in pre-loaders. Not much difference, but your main DOM would be cleaner.

Comment: The correct event name is `onload` with all lowercase, but I don't think there's a guarantee that the `<input>` tag will fire that event for an image button.  I can find no spec that says it's supported.

Comment: @jfriend00 HTML attributes are case-insensitive, I could write `OnLoAd` and it would work.

Comment: It doesn't trigger in Firefox either. I suspect it's a bug (maybe mis-labeled as a 'feature') in IE. Nothing in W3C about it, mind you.

Comment: Does this also occur in Safari? If so, then this is -webkit- based and I may have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a hack, but you can instantiate a Javascript `Image` object, and then set the event listener on that and then set the src of the input when it's done loading:

http://jsfiddle.net/t8n4y/

Disclaimer: only tested on Chrome

HTML:

```
<input type="image" id="imgInput" />
```

Javascript:

```
 var photo = document.getElementById('imgInput');
            var img = new Image();
            img.addEventListener('load', function () { alert("done loading"); }, false);
            img.src = 'http://jeremydouglass.com/gamertextually/images/gt_snowflake_tags-2-ach-large.png?ran=' + Math.random();
            photo.src = img.src;
```

Comment: @Kolink well, at least here the load event on img is legitimate.

Comment: Are you saying that HTML and JavaScript are not married and had inline event handlers as bastard children?

Comment: :-) I'm just saying that only a handful of elements accept the load event (off the top of my head: body, script, img, iframe)

Comment: Okay, but my "hack" seems much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I ran into a problem like this in the past.  You can detect it by doing the following:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var input = document.getElementById('input1');
    input.src='';
    input.addEventListener('load', loadImage, false);
    input.src = 'http://theoffguard.net/wp-content/upLoads/2012/04/Nick-Cage.jpg';
}

function loadImage()
{
  console.log("Image is loaded");
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsbin.com/ufovom/9/edit

Hope this helps!

Comment: How is this any different to the inline handler?

Comment: There really isn't one, but because of how Chrome handles `onload`, you need to do it like this.  I have made the changes to your original example: http://jsbin.com/ufovom/14/edit .  I believe this is a problem with -webkit-based browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="image" type="image" ... onLoad="this.style.opacity = 1" />

  //script ->

  $("#image").change(function () {
                if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var FR = new FileReader();
                FR.onload = function (e) {
                    //your onload
                };
                FR.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
});
```

Comment: Okay, you seem to be confusing `input[type=image]` with `input[type=file]`. But it's difficult to tell because you posted just plain code without any kind of explanation...

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [addEventListener()](http://help.dottoro.com/ljeuqqoq.php) method with a reference of your input.

Notice that before add the event listener to the input you'll need to let the page to load, for do it, just apply another event listener for the window object and then fire your function that reference your input.

Comment: Nope, makes no difference. I think I know how to use event listeners, thanks ;)

Comment: Plus, there's no way to install an event listener that guarentees it is installed before a cached image is loaded if the tag is in the HTML of the page.

Comment: Well I don't exactly know what are you trying to do mate, onload attr doesn't work on Chrome for some bug maybe, but I tried with js and it works (even changing the src each time), sorry if I'm being useless or I just repeated this a lot of times, (just trying to help)