# How to show div only after all the image inputs loaded?

Tags: html, jquery

I want the div "container" shows only after all image buttons in the div "inner" fully loaded. Or outer_1 and inner_1 show together after 1.jpg is loaded.

```
  <div class="container" id="top">
     <div class="outer" id="outer_1"><div class="inner" id="inner_1"><input type="image" src="1.jpg"></div></div>
     <div class="outer" id="outer_2"><div class="inner" id="inner_2"><input type="image" src="2.jpg"></div></div>
     <div class="outer" id="outer_3"><div class="inner" id="inner_3"><input type="image" src="3.jpg"></div></div>
 </div>
```

I have tried the below solution I found here but couldn't help. I am totally new in programming, may I know how can I do this?

```
    var $images = $('.inner input');
    var loaded_images_count = 0;

    $images.load(function(){
       loaded_images_count++;
       if (loaded_images_count == $images.length) {
           $('.container').show();
    }
    });
```

Comment: Related question with alternative solutions: [detect image input load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014163/detect-image-input-loading)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. The issue you have is that you're using the [`load()` method](https://api.jquery.com/load/), which is used to retrieve content from the server using AJAX, not the `load` event, which fires on `img` elements when they are ready to be displayed.

To fix this use [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `load()`:

```js
var $images = $('.inner input');
var loaded_images_count = 0;

$images.on('load', function() {
  loaded_images_count++;
  if (loaded_images_count == $images.length) {
    $('.container').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me neither. My $images.length is  0 even I can see the images.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, loaded doesn't mean rendered.

If you develop application on framework such as `Angular`, It will provided rendered event for you.
In case you develop application by only pure `javaScript` or even with `jQuery`,
Use `setTimeOut` might be help you (just in some case).

```
$images.load(function(){
   loaded_images_count++;
   if (loaded_images_count == $images.length) {
       setTimeout(function(){
           $('.container').show();
       }, 0);
}
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me neither. I am using Google App Script.